# How do I get the restoname from the db that has apostrophe on it? using the mysql or php

Tags: php, mysql

How do I get the restoname from the db that has apostrophe on it? using the mysql or php.

The code:
public function searchRestaurant($searchinfo){
$sql = "SELECT * FROM restaurants WHERE restoname = '$searchinfo' OR restocuisines = '$searchinfo'";
$result = $this->db->query($sql);
$result = $result->result('array');

```
    return $result;
}
```

The error:
[image: the error]

Comment: `mysql_real_escape_string($searchinfo);`

Comment: Your question will be better received if you type-in (or cut-n-paste) your code and errors rather than using images.

Comment: I've tried it. but I got this error!
Message: mysql_real_escape_string(): The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead